# What are "Republic of Cuba 4½s " referred to in The Intelligent Investor?

Tags: investing, terminology

I am on Chapter 6 of the Intelligent Investor - *Portfolio Policy for the Enterprising Investor: Negative Approach.* in the specific topic of Foreign Government Bonds.

It gave a brief intro about how historically since 1914 they have a bad history, but every few years or so the market conditions are in it's favour.

This is the direct quote I didn't understand, mainly, it's the number's in here. I don't know what they represent.

> But we do know that, if and when trouble should come the owner of foreign obligations has no legal or other means of enforcing his claim.

Right here...

> Those who bought Republic of Cuba **4½s** as high as 117 in 1953 saw them default their interest and then sell as low as 20 cents on the dollar in 1963.(edited)

What the heck does 4½s mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**4 1/2s** refers to a 4 1/2% coupon rate. Citation: http://www.ascecuba.org/asce_proceedings/cubas-hard-currency-debt/

> In June, 1937, the Republic of Cuba floated a $44.4 million note with
>   a forty-year maturity and a 4½ percent coupon. It is noteworthy that
>   Cuba was able to issue a note with a forty year maturity, reflecting
>   the bond market’s faith in the long term stability of the Cuban
>   Republic. The 4½ percent coupon, which is low by today’s standards,
>   was offered at 175 basis points above the current twenty-year U.S.
>   Treasury note.

Comment: Also, does `175 basis points above` mean, the priced at 175 of it's principal value?

Comment: A basis point is one hundredth of a percentage point. Thus, 175 basis points above means +1.75%. Put another way, the US Treasury note was at 2.75% at the time.